# Why are data types turning into "logical" ? R

Tags: r, variables

I have a data frame(call it: "df") that is organized by zip codes. I want to change "Zip" into a numeric data type, but when I apply "is.numeric" it turns it into a "logical" data type. It is also turning it into a "logical" data type when I try to turn other variables from "numeric" into "character" or any other data type.
Lines of code I've tried to change variable data types:

```
df$Zip = is.numeric(df$Zip)
df$Zip = is.numeric(is.character(df$Zip))
```

Data Overview:

```
'data.frame':   32989 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ Zip             : Factor w/ 32990 levels "01001","01002",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ MedianAge       : num  45.8 23.6 19.9 45.4 43.8 49.9 66.2 48.1 39.9 43.2 ...
 $ MedianAgeMale   : num  43.2 23.4 19.9 42.8 40.8 51.3 68.1 46.1 39.9 44.4 ...
```

My main goal is to create a subset which only includes Zip Codes ranging from 90001:97635 with the following line:

```
CAzipcodes = subset(df,Zip>90001 & Zip<97635)
```

It will not read the condition unless "Zip" is a "numeric" data type. If there are other ways to subset the data with a "factor" data type, please let me know.

Comment: You need to use `as.numeric()`.  `is.numeric()` is just TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The default method for is.numeric returns TRUE if its argument is of
>   mode "numeric" (type "double" or type "integer") and not a factor, and
>   FALSE otherwise. That is, is.integer(x) || is.double(x), or (mode(x)
>   == "numeric") && !is.factor(x).

So you want:

```
df$Zip = as.numeric(df$Zip)
```

or with dplyr and piping

```
df %<>% mutate(Zip = as.numeric(Zip))
```